# Fresh installation of Artifactory OSS 7.12.6 doesn't start, missing jffe service

Tags: artifactory

I have done everything according to manuals from https://jfrog.com/open-source/ :

My Ubuntu version is 20.04. Since there is no "focal"  in https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/artifactory-debs/, I've added "bionic":

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/artifactory.list
deb https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/artifactory-debs  bionic main
```

Then I've installed jfrog-artifactory-oss version 7.12.6 and tried launching the service.
It has launched, but browser, connected to ports :8081 or :8082 of localhost, shows that 3 services don't start:

[image]

So, what does it need?

Comment: This is further being discussed in https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-docker-examples/issues/210.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came here, because I had the very same problem on docker.
I finally figured out, that inside the docker the environment variables `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` where all set to `localhost:8080`. This caused the problem for me.

So when I start the docker this way, everything works as expected:

```
docker run --name artifactory-cpp-ce -ehttp_proxy="" -e https_proxy="" -e HTTP_PROXY="" -e HTTPS_PROXY="" -v $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-cpp-ce:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, I found that libvirtd was running. It wasn't libvirtd, itself, that prevented artifactory from coming up. It was the fact that the virbr0 interface was up. It doesn't seem to be a problem bringing this interface back up after artifactory comes up.

Answer (score 0):

For us this was on a Windows OS which was running McAfee Services. McAfee services listens on port 8081, same as the default Artifactory. Changing McAfee listening port was not an option for us.
I copied the JFROG_HOME\artifactory\var\etc\system.full-template.yaml, changed the name to system.yaml and searched for 8081 and changed it ( uncommented) to a different port. Restarted the Artifactory Service.